# How to test the self-updating mechanism in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I've developed a Firefox extension, packaged it with `jpm` and have successfully in-line installed it on my local machine. It is self-hosted, and intended to be self-updating. I've followed the instructions at [Automatic Add-on Update Checking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Automatic_Add-on_Update_Checking) as well as at [Supporting updates for self-hosted addons in JPM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Supporting_updates_for_self-hosted_add-ons).

My question is, how do I test that the self-updating mechanism is working, and debug it if it isn't? My web server is correctly serving the .xpi and the .update.rdf. When I click "Check for updates" in the Firefox Add-ons menu it finds the update.rdf, which has a higher version number than the add-on I've locally installed, but it always says "No updates found".

There are no errors in the add-on debugging window when I click "check for updates".

I've seen and fixed [this issue](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/409) in my update.rdf but I am not sure if there are others lurking. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This just in: it works sometimes and not other times. Investigating further...

Comment: flipping `extensions.logging.enabled` pref might be useful to follow the process in the Browser Console